# Google Drive Site Loads Unstyled

Tags: html, css, google-drive

[This page (Biology Lessons) on Google Drive](https://5e951c14064973bf83b51818d7c43173152ca8f3.googledrive.com/host/0B0FDz6Brn925LVVpSDNvME92Rkk) loads unstyled for some reason (the `Introduction/index.html` loads fine).

I've checked my HTML and CSS files with W3C's validators and everything checked out OK. I've deleted and remade both the `index.html` and `assets/stylesheets/index.css` files. I've even changed the location and name of the root folder in Google Drive; nothing worked.

The external fonts and all the other assets load fine; it's just the `assets/stylesheets/index.css` file.

Plus, when I launch it through Chrome Dev Editor it shows up like it should:

[image: Screenshot]

What do I have to do to get this thing to load right on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete and reupload that file, but make sure that you have it as a `.css` file before you upload it.

The reason being is that Google will turn your file's MIME type to `text/plain` instead of `text/css` due to the specific way they process files when they are uploaded.

[Also, web hosting support in Drive is ending soon.](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)

Comment: Will it take time? Because it's not working.

Comment: Try deleting and reuploading that file, but make sure that you have it as a .css file before you upload it. Also, [web hosting support in Drive is ending soon.](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)

Comment: It worked! You should add that to the answer.

Comment: All right, then.